# Eel Python : how to return loop values from python function to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, eel

I have been trying to return loop output from my python function to java-script using eel library.

**My eel code -**

```
import eel

eel.init(".")


@eel.expose

def login_details(login_email,login_pass):
    for i in range(10):
        return(i)  

eel.start("index.html", size=(650,612))
```

**My Javascript code -**

```
<script>
      login_email = document.getElementById("email");      
      login_pass = document.getElementById("pass");

      function details() 
      {
        eel.login_details(login_email.value,login_pass.value)(login_check);
      }

      function login_check(stat)
      { 
          console.log(stat) <!-- prints the value of i -->
      }
    </script>
```

I was expecting the output to be a series of values from 0-10 but the `console.log(stat)` prints only 0. how do i make my JS print all the `i` values?

Comment: You return which breaks the loop after the first iteration. To return a list create it from range: `list(range(11))`. Edit: also the end value of range is **exclusive**, so to get 0-10 you need `range(11)`

Comment: @ivvija what if i want the value to be passed to the JS with each iteration without making a list? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Never used `eel`, but I guess you want to callback for each iteration. Have you tried manually calling the JS `login_check` using `eel.login_check(i)` from python?